# Is there a lightweight desktop music player app/solution that reads directly from my iDevice iTunes library?

Tags: music

I have an *iPod touch 4G* (**jailbroken**) dedicated for storing music.

To clarify, I want an app/solution that:

1. runs on OS X Mavericks/Windows 8.1
2. reads from the itunes library on my iDevice, which is connected to the computer preferably via USB
3. plays music

By "solution", I even mean things like "SSH into the ROOT file system and stream the mp3 files from `itunes_control" folder".

Please don't nominate iTunes. It's too bulky to be always around. However, it's okay to require iTunes and/or its components installed.

Many thanks!

Comment: Both sites are ok, key point is not to post a question to several sites as well. If you don't get good answers here in a few days, just flag the question and we can help you to migrate it to SoftwareRecommendations.

Comment: To clarify...you're asking for an application that plays music that's stored on your phone, on your computer? There are several products available to do this on Mac. Searching Google for "mac airplay receiver" is a good start. I'm not personally familiar with any of them, so can't give a recommendation. AirServer's site is pretty though. :P

Comment: @tubedogg Thanks for the hint! :) I should have made it more clear. I want an app that: (1)runs on OSX/Windows (2)reads from the itunes library on my iDevice, connected preferably via usb (3)plays music.

Comment: Streaming from your device over USB is going to be a sticking point probably. I'm not aware of any software that does this. The search I mentioned lists several applications that will do it over WiFi, though.

Comment: Winamp but it only works on Windows